# How to tell how much an individual job costs

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Is there a way to tell how much an individual training job cost?

I can see the daily / hourly costs in the billing dashboard, which is a good proxy. I looked at the usage report as well, but didn't see a way to get the UsageValues to add up, and din't see tags coming through into the usage report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor Customer Service question and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: This is not a pricing question, but about a programmatic way to control the cost of using the cloud for training jobs

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling the [DescribeTrainingJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/describe-training-job.html) API call, you are getting the following values: TrainingStartTime and TrainingEndTime. You are billed for the time interval between these times.

Now you need to get the next two values to complete the cost calculation, under ResourceConfig (in the same API call output): InstanceType, and InstanceCount.

Lastly, you can query the [pricing API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-list-api-update-new-query-and-metadata-functions/) for the InstanceType you are using and get the price for the region you are running.

```
import boto3
pricing_client = boto3.client('pricing', region_name='us-east-1')
filterValue = instanceType + "-Training"

response = pricing_client.get_products(
    ServiceCode='AmazonSageMaker',
    Filters=[
        {
            'Type': 'TERM_MATCH',
            'Field': 'instanceType',
            'Value': filterValue
        },
    ]
)
## TODO: fix this line to take the right region and not the first
python_dict = json.loads(response['PriceList'][0])

pricePerHour = next(iter(next(iter(python_dict['terms']['OnDemand'].values()))["priceDimensions"].values()))["pricePerUnit"]['USD']
return float(pricePerHour)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You should use the `BillableTimeInSeconds` value returned by DescribeTrainingJob api to calculate the cost.